# how to replace ALL words in a thesis with a phrase: All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy

Tags: automation

I just finished my thesis. What a mouthful, oh boy. So. For fun, I think I'd like to replace ALL words in the whole thesis with the phrase from The Shinning: All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Just because.

I'm thinking, it should keep the lists, chapter, subchapter headings and so on. But replace all normal text, the content of lists, the content of footnotes, citations, captions of figures, and so on. Like so:[image]

I have no idea how to do this. Most likely, doing it by hand is the only way. But. Maybe you smart folks know how?

I know it is quite silly. Hope you don't find this question offensive in it's pointlessnes.

Comment: look at the chickenize package it has loads of useful features for this sort of thing.

Comment: Allright, will check it out and supply the answer here, if I find one. Thank you.

Comment: It would also work great as an alternative Lorem Ipsum :D